# Difference between glibC and bioniC

Tags: c, optimization, glibc, built-in, bionic

Hi i have some problems with optimization.
I tried to compile one of gcc test with builtin functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef HAVE_C99_RUNTIME
double test1 (double x)
{
  return __builtin_pow (x, 1/3);
}

double test2 (double x)
{
  return __builtin_pow (x, 4./3.);
}

double test3a (double x)
{
  return __builtin_pow (x, 5./3.);
}

double test3b (double x)
{
  return __builtin_pow (x, -5./3.);
}

double test4 (double x)
{
  return __builtin_pow (x, 7./3.);
}
#endif
```

I tried to compile it with next 2 ways:
**1 way:**
`gcc -mglibc -O -ffast-math -std=c99 -fno-ident -S -o builtins-58.s`
And in output assembler file all `call pow` was changed to `call cbrt` - its expected

**2 way:**
`gcc -mbionic -O -ffast-math -std=c99 -fno-ident -S -o builtins-58.s`
With using `-mbionic` instead of`-mglibc` i got output with `call pow`

Does anybody know how `optmimization` for `builtin` functions works in `Bionic`

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant  Why optimization of builtin functions different for glibc and bionic?

Comment: Do the functions return the same values?

Comment: The source code for both is readily available.  Why not just take a look at it?

Comment: @HansPassant I can't find difference in case of using optimization options for builtin math functions

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant I don't know it yet. I am intrested in assembly output with optimization.

Comment: Either I don't understand your question, or I have a hard time understanding why it would be notable that two different codebases (two implementations of libc) could be compiled into different machine instructions.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant I understand that 2 different implementations of libc can provide different machine instructions, but i want found this place in code of this libraries or something like this in overview  for this libraries.

Comment: You mean you need help locating where in the source code for pow() is located in glibc source code and in bionic source code? Also there are not different code paths for different optimization levels. Somehow I get the feeling you ask for one thing, but really should be asking some other question, you just don't know it yet. (I don't mean to be disrespectful btw.)

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant Firstly i don't understand why I have different output, but now it's became celar for me (different libraries have different implementations). 
And now i want to find difference of using  optimizations with math in this libraries (Bionic and glibc).

Comment: @Pepelac, then you should read the source code of these libraries. It is probably different. Also, it's COMPLETELY up to the compiler how it chooses to translate to the source to machine instructions. If you switch compilers, you may get yet *another* output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happens becuse of in gcc 4.7 we have special check (check for `TARGET_C99_FUNCTIONS`)
in `builins.def` file, where is defined all builtin function.

And in another file we have:
`define TARGET_C99_FUNCTIONS (OPTION_GLIBC)`

These check checks library, and if there no `glibc` then we don't have `cbrt` function.
So we cant transform `pow` to `cbrt` and it's the root cause.